# Elasticsearch warning messages

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I have ES running on my local development machine for my Rails app (Using Searchkick).  I am getting these error messages:

> 299 Elasticsearch-6.8.8-2f4c224 "In a future major version, this
> request will fail because this action would add [1] total shards, but
> this cluster currently has [1972]/[1000] maximum shards open. Before
> upgrading, reduce the number of shards in your cluster or adjust the
> cluster setting [cluster.max_shards_per_node]."

My config file already has `cluster.max_shards_per_node: 2000`.  Am I missing something here?

> 299 Elasticsearch-6.8.8-2f4c224 "[types removal] The parameter
> include_type_name should be explicitly specified in create index
> requests to prepare for 7.0. In 7.0 include_type_name will default to
> 'false', and requests are expected to omit the type name in mapping
> definitions."

I have zero clue where to start looking on this one.

These flood my terminal when I run my re-indexing - looking to resolve it.

Comment: Did the "answer" help?  What did you actually do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is dynamic cluster setting an you should use [_cluster/settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html) API.

obviously  it is very wrong that have this number of shards in one node. please read followning article:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster

you can use shrink index API. The shrink index API allows you to shrink an existing index into a new index with fewer primary shards

Comment: I am going to have a look at these solutions. I must have misunderstood the shard limit thinking I had to increase to 2000 to solve this. So I need to go lower?

Comment: the problem is not about limit. it is about you have too many shard in your cluster. you should decrease number of shards per indices.